# SharePoint List Ping IP Address

Tags: query

We have setup a SharePoint page with a list of our office sites.
At the moment we have a column called status so in the event of an infrastructure outage, we manually change the status from Connected to Outage.

Ideally we would like to be able to somehow have a list of IP addresses per site and somehow maybe via a calculated column or some kind of lookup ping that IP address and if the IP returns with no response then set the status to Outage and automatically back to Connected when returns ping response.

I've already had a quick google and cant see that this has been done before but thought it would be pretty awesome to get this working!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A calculated field will not help:

- It's only calculated when the item is changes
- It can not do anything sophisticated

It would be better to have a TimerJob/service running at using the list as input and writing back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't say Calculated Columns can't do anything sophisticated.

They can run all the JavaScript you want.
It's just impossible to debug... see http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/

But its better to use CSR Client Side Rendering on 2013